# half size wheel covers

Tags: wheels

IS there such a thing ? Preferably on ebay. They should cover the hub and studs. Hopefully I'll get understood. English is not my native language so here is how a full size wheel cover looks like:

[image]

Comment: What specific wheel are they supposed to fit? The only "half size wheel covers" I've seen are for big trucks, they cover the hub and studs, like you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search Google for "hub covers"

[image]